# Possible Plumbing Acid through Leaky Pipe in Floating Ceiling, How to Test/Clean?

Tags: acid-base, polymers, safety, cleaning

So I had a plumber in the other day, and I don't know if he used acid drain cleaner or not. The pipe where the possible leak is, is over some drop ceiling (vinyl or expanded polystyrene).

Before I go probe around and clean it, how do I test if the liquid is indeed an acid? Is it safe to handle, given it may have been there for about a week? I know for sure:

- There was no smell associated with the plumbing on that day.
- There is still a single, small wet spot on drop ceiling tile.
- There is no sign of a hole being corroded through the ceiling tile.

In short, how do I handle this clean up?

Comment: Do you mean there is a leak in the plumbing ? If so, I would not suspect material used to clean pipe. I would look to find the source of the leak.

Comment: Is the pipe metallic or made of some plastic ? A simple way of checking the acidity of liquid is using sodium bicarbonate $\ce{NaHCO3}$, this white powder will react and make bubbles, foam or moss if some acidity is present.

Answer (score 1):

It's highly unlikely a chemical drain cleaner was acid; if one was used, it's far more likely to have been a strong base. That said, the best thing to do is:

> Call the plumber and ask what was used and how to clean it up.